# Variable + insertText Swift deleteBackward() + insertText(". ")

Tags: xcode, swift, keyboard

I'm making a custom keyboard. I want an auto period function but my code has an error.Please help me solve it

**Code:**

```
@IBAction func autoPeriod(button: UIButton) {
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward() + insertText(". ")
}
```

Cheers,

Palash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

**Code:**

```
@IBAction func autoPeriod(button: UIButton) {
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).deleteBackward()
    (textDocumentProxy as UIKeyInput).insertText(".")
}
```